# Attach item to campaign after deployment

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, campaign

Let me reword this:

I'd like to attach an email to a campaign, in campaign manager, after it has already deployed and still have the stats (opens, clicks, etc...) show up in the campaign for reporting purposes. I ask this because the email was not attached to said campaign before it was deployed. I would like to access the statistics for this email in the campaign for reporting purposes.

Is there any way to do this or do I need to have ExactTarget do this on their own back-end databases?

Comment: not quite sure what you are asking. Are you asking if you can add an attachment to an email that was already sent? Please clarify

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can.  Click on the email, select properties and then edit.  From here you can add the campaign from the upper right side.